# How to pass a variable number of components to a blazor component

Tags: c#, blazor

I´m trying to build a base dialog component for my Blazor webapp, that is supposed to transition between different child components that represent the steps of the dialog.

But so far I've not found a way to pass a variable number of different components to this base dialog.

I would like the usage to look like something like this:

```
<Dialog>
    <DialogItem>
        @*SomeComponent*@
    </DialogItem>
    <DialogItem>
        @*AnotherComponent*@
    </DialogItem>
</Dialog>
```

There are some component libaries (like Mudblazor) that have components that work like that, so it should be possible right?

The only thing I could find so far was something like this:

```
@typeparam inputType

@foreach(var item in Items)
{
   @Template(TItem)
}

@code{
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment<inputType> Template { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public List<inputType> Items { get; set; }
}
```

But that does not allow me to render items in the list differently or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach here is to make the parent component (a `<Dialog>` here) a cascading component that the child components can detect and then call to add themselves to the list as they are rendered.

Steve Sanderson demonstrated this in his Tab component, an example of this is here:
https://gist.github.com/SteveSandersonMS/f10a552e1761ff759b1631d81a4428c3

Comment: That looks like it does what I need, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In case someone stumbles on this in the future, this is what I ended up with:

Dialog component:

```
<CascadingValue Value="this">
    @ChildContent
</CascadingValue>

@ActiveNode?.Value.ChildContent

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }

    LinkedList<DialogItem> DialogItems { get; } = new();

    LinkedListNode<DialogItem>? ActiveNode { get; set; }

    public void Add(DialogItem item)
    {
        DialogItems.AddLast(item);
        if (ActiveNode is null)
        {
            ActiveNode = DialogItems.First;
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }
    public void Next()
    {
        if (ActiveNode != DialogItems.Last)
            ActiveNode = ActiveNode?.Next;
    }
    public void Previous()
    {
        if (ActiveNode != DialogItems.First)
            ActiveNode = ActiveNode?.Previous;
    }
}
```

DialogItem component:

```
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }

    [CascadingParameter]
    Dialog? ParentDialog { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        ParentDialog?.Add(this);
    }
}
```